# Getting an image into the background

Tags: html

I'm trying to get an image in to the background of a css box I have made

I'm confused on the pathing to get the image to appear

C:\Users\James\Documents\tournmentwebsite (the  .jpg image is inside the tournmentwebsite folder)

I'm new to stack overflow I had a look at the other question I'm still a little confused

Comment: Please show us the code you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct img src for an image that is my own and not borrowed from another website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037289/what-is-the-correct-img-src-for-an-image-that-is-my-own-and-not-borrowed-from-an)

Comment: Css

div.loginborder{
 max-width:600px;
 margin:auto;
 border: 3px solid #e8b409;
 background-color: #1e0442;
 background-image: url("lolimage.jpg");
 }

Sorry if this is the incorrect way to do this I'm new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

I have figure out the issue. It wasn't cacheing correctly. All i had to do was press ctrl f5 and the image appeared on the page :)

Answer (score 0):

Would you like set an image on the background of the box?
If I have understood, you could use `background-image: url(" "); .`

Comment: yes, Sorry if I've asked the question really unprofessionally. I'm dyslexic and totally new to stack over flow

Comment: It's still not working which is very strange.

I'll try explain again because it's probably me that's causing the confusion.

my css file. is located in the same document (tournamentwebsite) as my php. my .jph image is also in the same document.