# Image do not load in react.js

Tags: html, reactjs, image

So very simply I want to put an image in my page. Previously I put a background image on it, it is working well.
I don't get any error just a little picture icon on the screen.
I use React.js
I keep the pictures in src/assets folder

The images in jpg format I try to change it in png this does not helped. I think I just not notice something simple. I tried to add the image with simple html method, and with react component method as well. I write a code example below.

App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import './App.css';
 import Television from './components/television/Television'

 export default function App() {
  const title = 'xy';

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome on {title}</h1>
      <div className='television'>
        <img src='assets/television.jpg'/>
      </div>
      <Television/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Television.js

```
import React from "react";

function Television() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src="assets/television.jpg"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Television;
```

I know this two way the same I just tried it. I attach a screen about the little picture images on the screen.

This is it.
[image]

Comment: Finally I find a way to fix it. Just create a new folder inside the public folder and put the images here from the src folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add images dynamically like this:

```
<img src={require(../assets/television.jpg)} />
```

Please make sure the path to your image is correct
[Here to learn how to set local images paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037289/what-is-the-correct-img-src-for-an-image-that-is-my-own-and-not-borrowed-from-an)

Answer (score -1):

I think that image path is incorrect.
Your component position is "components/television/Television" so that means deeps is two from app component and assets folder deep is zero.
so image path became like this :`<img src="../../assets/television.jpg"/>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).